# Should I make a constants class for my annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, constants

Which is better?

1. `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`
2. `@SuppressWarnings(AnnotationConstants.UNCHECKED)`

Where `AnnotationConstants` is a typical constants class...

```
public final class AnnotationConstants {
    private AnnotationConstants() { }

    public static final String UNCHECKED = "unchecked";

    ...
}
```

I know that there are a lot of general arguments for and against constants classes--and that's exactly what I'm **not** interested in. I want to know if a constants class **specifically** for annotations is a good idea or a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this *specific* example I'd stick with literals. After all, you're trying to suppress warnings - if you use the wrong literal, the warning won't be suppressed, which will draw your attention to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say a little bit of both, please.

In Spring, you could say something like @Scope(Scopes.SESSION) or @Scope(Scopes.REQUEST), which attaches a specific kind of behavior to the annotation so I'd say *always* use a constants class, which is good for traceability.

If you're just supressing warnings, there's little likelyhood that you want to really trace this, so just go with the literal.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with Holsam for SuppressWarnings - use the strings

If you're writing your own annotation, I'd recommend usng enums where possible for things that could be represented as a set of constants

Comment: I like the idea of using enums. +1.

Answer (score 0):

For `@SuppressWarning` and the likes, I don't think so. I prefer writing the constants directly, and have the compiler check them if possible. Eclipse does a nice job at that.